# Magento white screen after disabling Mage Module output in Advanced Configuration

Tags: magento, module, screen, mage

I'm developing a Magento store and there is a guy that manages the store, we were transferring the store to another domain but the old one was with all products.

The guy went in advanced configurations and disabled all modules in the old Magento installation, even the Mage ones and now the initial page is white and the admin is too, what could I do to solve this problem?

The version of Magento is 1.9.1.1.

Comment: White as in completely blank? That's likely a 50x error. Check the php and webserver logs and post relevant entries.

Comment: Yes, completely blank. Take a look, this is the link:
http://www.saiajustamodafesta.com.br/loja_estava_funcionando/

Comment: Indeed, no content at all says you likely had an error. Turn up error_reporting and examine the logs I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry but where I can turn up this?

Comment: In php.ini. You'll likely also want to ensure display_errors and display_startup_errors is enabled. See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting for more information

Comment: It's easy, core Mage module output was disabled leading to the expected result. No need to bother troubleshooting this, you need to put Magento back in operation by re-enabling Mage module output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, he disabled all the Mage modules, including REMOVE ENGINE ie Mage Core?

Hmm...

Ok, here's what you do.

Use phpMyAdmin to open `core_config_data`, sort table by path and look for all the paths beginning with `advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_` and change the value from `1` to `0`

Then delete all the `mage--?` subfolders in `var/cache/` so Magento is forced to reload the configuration data out of the `core_config_data` table.

This should put your engine back in so the old jalopy will run.

Comment: Sweet to hear! And thankfully, reasonably easy to reverse. Some of those Mage modules are kind of essential and others have odd dependencies which can really mess things up when they're deactivated. Flip a bit in the database, clear cache and step back from the abyss...